# Figure caption in Rmarkdown with ggvis

Tags: r, r-markdown, caption, ggvis

I have problems getting captions working for ggvis plots in a Rmarkdown documents (html-output). I have tried "everything" but with no luck.

To keep it very simple, here is an example of the problem:
 If I use the code chunk below in Rmarkdown, everything is okey, and my caption is popping up below the plot:

````
```{r, message = FALSE, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is a caption test"}

plot(cars)

```
````

but if I try to make a similar ggvis plot like this, the caption does not appear.

````
```{r, message = FALSE, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is a caption test"}

ggvis(cars, ~speed, ~dist)

```
````

Maybe I have just misunderstood some fundamental things, but do hope somebody can take me in the right direction.

Best regards,
Olav